# Emacs email Gnus split method as read

Tags: email, emacs, archive, gnus

I use Gnus in emacs as my mail service. Because I have several computers and many email addresses, I use an extra address to store my sent messages. Since I use gnus on several computers during the day, I want to sync my sent mail and to do so by pop3 downloading my sent mail to my archives.sent folder; so far, no problem. But now I want to make sure all those downloaded messages, while available in my sent folder, are not marked as unread; they should not call that attention to themselves.

Is there a simple way to use split mail (or something else) to mark them as read as soon as they are sorted? It would be a pain to have to use catch-up on them every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, my goal is to prevent Gnus from highlighting "archive.sent" as a group with unread messages. This goal is satisfied by unsubscribing from the group, going to it in the message buffer and pressing <kbd>u</kbd>. Now it will not show up in the group list, even when unread messages are contained therein, unless I list all groups with <kbd>L</kbd>.